# Is there a word for someone who now wants to be known as a native of a country?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, someone born in London but who moved to Wales at a young age and therefore wants to be known as a Welshman rather than an Englishman?

Comment: ...a _wannabe_ Welshman?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it counts as one word but you could use a *[self-identifying](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/self-identify)* Welshman.

From [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/self-identify):

> **self-identify**
>
> VERB [INTRANSITIVE]
>   to decide and say who you are without the need for external checks or proof

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/332386)

Comment: Strange comment. I don't understand why it doesn't provide an answer. It's possible that I didn't understand the question as you did. Presumably that makes you right and me wrong because...

Comment: That comment is auto-generated from review queues. I figured it isn't a word, so clicked the option for "doesn't answer the question"

Answer (score 1):

"Native" comes from the Latin word for 'born'. A person born in London can *never* become a "native" Welsh person, except maybe, at a stretch, to Welsh parents who were visiting. As S Conroy notes, a person who moved to Wales at a young age might come to "identify" as Welsh. Your question ignores 50% of the human race by supposing that the imaginary person always wants to be a "Welsh**man**".